# Create summarizing dataframe in a fast way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I want to summarize into a new dataframe: 
The original dataframe has a person, a date, and three dummy categories - football, tennis and volleyball indicating that a person has played that sport the date (grey table)

I want to make a "summary df" that shows how many times the person has played each sport each quarter (blue table). Is there any way to do this really efficient, for when the dataframe consists of more than 100 different people and several hundred thousand dates? I'm a bit at a loss and appreciate any answer!

[image]

Comment: 1) Consider adding your data as text, not image. 2) have a look at `pivot` and `pivot_table`.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Sure, that is noted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is converting datetimes to quarters and years by [`Series.dt.quarter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.quarter.html) and [`Series.dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) and then aggregate `sum`:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
df1 = (df.groupby(['Person', 
                   dates.dt.quarter.rename('Quarter'), 
                   dates.dt.year.rename('Year')], sort=False)
         .sum()
         .reset_index())
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I will give this a try!